# Images not loading

Tags: image, loading

I have images uploaded to my server and only images in the "social" directory load, but others in "best" and "recent" don't load. The index file is in a public_html directory, along with the images directory in which the "social", "recent", and "best" directories are held:

```
/public_html
    index.php
    /images
        /social
        /best
        /recent
```

**Edit:**

My code for finding social images is as follows:

```
<img src="images/social/twitter.png" alt="Twitter Logo"/>
```

My code for finding recent images is as follows:

```
<a href="images/recent/wasteLarge.png" title="Click to enlarge."><img src="images/recent/waste.png" alt="Graffiti" class="recent_1"></a>
```

My code for finding best images is as follows:

```
<li><a href="images/best/vwLarge.png" title="Click to enlarge."><img src="images/best/vw.png" alt="VW MK2 Model"></a></li>
```

**Edit:**
As it turns out, even the EXTENSIONS on the server are case sensitive, which was a big smack on the forehead.

Comment: How are you linking to images in the other directories: "social", "best", etc.?

Comment: I have edited the original post. Hope it helps.

Comment: There is no reason this shouldn't link to the images. What are the permissions on the "recent" and "best" folders? Put them to 777 and see if this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by put them to 777?

Comment: Apache has permissions for folders. 777 is full permissions, the folder might be set to 000 (no permissions). That's the only reason I can think of why the images are not being shown. Have you tried opening the images in a new tab?

Comment: I have and I'm getting files not found. If it helps, here's the live site: http://mattcdecker.comeze.com/